# How to make an emf into a character marker symbol north arrow?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, cartography

I have an emf that I would like to make into a North Arrow. How do I get the emf to be a Character Marker Symbol in ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For starters, see the following help articles:**

- [About Creating New Symbols](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_creating_new_symbols/00s600000004000000/)
- [Creating Marker Symbols](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_marker_symbols/00s600000002000000/)

**To create a custom north arrow symbol in ArcGIS 10, follow these steps:**

1. In ArcMap, go to **Customize** -> **Style Manager**
2. Select your default profile's style or create a new one
3. Right click **North Arrows** in the list of categories on the right and click **New**->**North Arrow...**
4. Click **Symbol**
5. Click **Edit Symbol**
6. From the **Type** dropdown select **Picture Marker Symbol**
7. Browse to and select your desired image (must be in **BMP** or **EMF** format) and click **Open**
8. Adjust the **size**, and **X and Y offset** properties as needed. For the north arrow to rotate correctly, carefully set the X and Y offsets so that the visual center point of the arrow is at the center of the symbol preview.
9. Click **OK** / **Close** until you are back to ArcMap
10. Ensure your **Data Frame rotation** is at **0** before continuing using either the **Data Frame properties** - **General** tab or the **Data Frame Tools** toolbar
11. Go to **Insert** -> **North Arrow**
12. Select the north arrow style you created (if it doesn't appear check that your style is selected under **More Styles**)
13. Right-click the new north arrow and go to **Properties**
14. On the **Size and Position** tab, set the **Anchor Point** to the center so that when the data frame is rotated, the symbol rotates around its center instead of a corner.
15. Click OK
16. If necessary, use the **Rotate Data Frame** tool on the **Data Frame Tools** toolbar to rotate the data frame to the correct angle or type it in to the box.

I was able to use MS Paint to create a 64x64 version of the GIS.SE logo as a north arrow in BMP format (I would have liked to use vector but the [vector version of the logo](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/748/vector-gis-se-logo-for-use-in-posters-presentations) appears to still be MIA). Here's what it looks like on a page layout with a rotated data frame:

[image: Custom North Arrow with rotated data frame]